# Multiline Textbox Resizing in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox, multiline, splitcontainer

I have two multiline textboxes separated within a splitContainer.  When I drag the splitter left or right I would like the textboxes to resize accordingly.  How do I do this?  I am using Microsoft Visual C# 2008 Express Edition.  Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you set the Dock property of textboxes to Dock.Fill, this should happen for you.

Answer (score 1):

Two ways:

1. Set the Textbox.Anchor property to Top, Left, Bottom and Right.
2. Set the Textbox.Dock property to Fill.

Answer (score 0):

I believe all you need to do is set the anchor property to Top, Left, Bottom, Right true.

> Control..::.Anchor Property
>
> Gets or sets the edges of the
>   container to which a control is bound
>   and determines how a control is
>   resized with its parent.

Answer (score 0):

You should Dock them in each panel.

Comment: This is only true if the text boxes fill the panels they are children of.

Answer (score 0):

Very late to the party but all I did was set dock to fill and Multiline to true and it filled the space.

Answer (score -1):

Just set the `TextBox` style like this

```
.MultiLineTextBox
        {
            max-height: 52px;
            max-width: 163px;
            min-height: 52px;
            min-width: 163px;
        }
<asp:TextBox ID="txtremark" runat="server" CssClass ="MultiLineTextBox"
```

and enjoy.

Comment: The question asks about WinForms, not ASP.net